# How to build AJTCL Base Services?

Tags: alljoyn

I want to build AJTCL Base Services and run the tcl base services samples (notification, controllee etc).

I can build the AJTCL core successfully.

But when I build the base_tcl with the given instructions at the https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/building/thin-linux page it fails.

I both tried 15.09 and master

```
scons WS=off AJ_TCL_ROOT=../../core/ajtcl/

scons: Reading SConscript files ...

Checking for uncrustify command...(cached) no

Checking for AllJoyn library ajtcl...no

Checking for C function AJ_EnableSoftAP()... (cached) no

Missing required external libraries
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can manage to build the master branches of the both AJTCL and BASE_TCL as of March 11.

Just be sure to build the AJTCL first and then build the BASE_TCL by using the AJTCL outputs.

You can also check it at the base_tcl's SConstruct file, there is *AJTCL_DIST* variable which should point to the AJCTL's dist folder.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at our [Jenkins](http://build.allseenalliance.org/baseservices%20Base%20Services%20CI), in particular the console output of [this job](https://build.allseenalliance.org/baseservices/job/BaseV15.09_CoreV15.09a_TCL_Linux/label=rac-ord-asa-ci-ubuntu64-2,variant=debug/2/console), to see exactly how we build the SDKs.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it helps me a lot!